# Voiceflow API isssue with Airtable

Tags: json, chatbot, airtable

While I'm using VoiceFlow for my chatbot application prototype, I find an error. When I was trying to connect my Airtable API with the Voiceflow API, I saw some changes. Everything was working perfectly, but the main issue was that the tutorial I was following was showing (Blue colour ss), and after sending a request from Voiceflow, they could copy the record ID, which I could not find in my voiceflow attached ss (white colour ss). Is there anyone who is familiar with both voiceflow and airtable? Please let me know to solve the issue.

[image]

[image]

I try some solution provided by YouTube but there was not enough resource.